# Event Handling with Nested functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, nested-function

The below code is to change the background color of the button and it runs fine.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>check</title>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

     function checkRun(){
      var obj = {
            client: 'Corporate',
            number: 5541,
            type: 'CL',
            fnct : function (){
                btn.style.backgroundColor='red' ;
             }
        }
      var btn = document.querySelector('button');
      btn.onclick = obj.fnct();

    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
     <input type='text' name='checkName' id='check1' value='val1' class='class1'/><br><br>
     <button type='button' name='checkName' id='check3' value='val3' class='class3' onclick='checkRun()'>Hello</button>

</body>
</html>
```

When I change the function call as below, the background color is changing only when I click the button twice. I don't understand the reason behind this behavior.

Please explain.

```
btn.onclick = function () {
    obj.fnct();
}
```

Comment: No, the color is changing on the first click itself with the original code. @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you attempt the second format, you are registering a handler function which will invoked on click. The new handler will get triggered only on the next click

In the first approach you are calling the `fnct` function and assigns the value returned by it(undefined in this case) as the click handler

Instead you can move your script to the bottom of the page and directly register the click handler without the `checkRun` method

```js
var obj = {
  client: 'Corporate',
  number: 5541,
  type: 'CL',
  fnct: function() {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}

var btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', obj.fnct);
```

```html
<input type='text' name='checkName' id='check1' value='val1' class='class1' /><br><br>
<button type='button' name='checkName' id='check3' value='val3' class='class3'>Hello</button>
```